# Getting Tweets From Particular User From The Last Fetch Using MaxId

Tags: java, twitter4j

We are using twitter4j userTimeLine for getting tweets from particular user. How do I use maxId and How do I fetch tweets from the last fetch of tweets???

My source code as follows,

```
public List<Status> userTimeLine(String keyWord, int page, int count) {

        log.info("Showing user timeline.");

        List<Status> statuses = new ArrayList<Status>(0);
        Paging paging = new Paging(page, count);
        try {
            statuses = twitter.getUserTimeline(keyWord, paging);
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            log.error("Unable to find user timeline", e);
        }

        return statuses;
    }
```

This code returns 100 tweets for the first fetch. In the second fetch, it retrieves 102 [100(last fetched tweets)+2 (new tweets)] if there new tweets posted by the user. Otherwise it returns the same 100 tweets for each and every fetch.

How do I solve getting tweets from the last fetch of tweets?

Comment: Put your code please, we can see sthg on it.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify tweets (by status id) using Paging to get the tweets that were posted in between using the sinceId and maxId methods.

```
 since_id: returns elements which id are bigger than the specified id
 max_id: returns elements which id are smaller than the specified id
```

For example:

```
 Paging paging = new Paging(1, 10).sinceId(258347905419730944L).maxId(258348815243960320L);
 List<Status> statuses = twitter.getHomeTimeline(paging);
```

You can find lots of things [here](https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/tree/master/twitter4j-core/src/main/java/twitter4j) :  , and also you can use sthg like that;

```
 Query query = new Query("from:somebody").since("2011-01-02");
 Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
 QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);
```

Comment: Semih.. Can you explain how do I get the value of sinceId and maxId?

Comment: Instead of using sinceId or maxId, it more usefull and easy to use pagination. You must look pagination, I will send you a small sample code :)

Comment: Look at this SST(especially 6 - Pagination control), you can find lots of sample code about getting tweets; http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html

Comment: I got a solution... Thanks Semih... :)